# Linking to Facebox from Google map Info Window v3

Tags: google-maps, infowindow, facebox

Hello using Google maps V3 Infowindow with link, If click on the link I want to show the information in a FaceBox. The only problem I have is that I cannot get it to work when linked to from an info window. It works perfectly when linked to from a regular link.  Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong to prevent it from working? I have all of the necessary .css and .js files on the server. I know these are placed correctly since, i am using the same facebox in the same page works perfectly when linked to from a regular link 
This is my below code to load the content in infowindow

```
<div class="mt">
    <div class="fl"> 
<a id="detailsLink" class="jsDetailsLink" href="/profile/201/Brehead" rel="facebox">More profile information</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

This just loads as a new page in the browser window (It is supposed to load into a Facebox window) 
Thanks to everyone who is so kind as to help me out. I am fairly new to google maps and appreciate all assistance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google map infowindow loaded with link, after click that link it will open in Facebox in google maps v3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706125/google-map-infowindow-loaded-with-link-after-click-that-link-it-will-open-in-fa)

Comment: to accept an answer, you just click the tick that appears beside the answer when you hover beside it. It is courteous to do this when people answer your questions. People are more likely to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Info Windows are not clickable. If you want to add a clickable hyperlink then you should add an [Infobubble.](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html) The javascript for this can be found at [this link](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/infobubble/src/infobubble.js?r=356). Note that these were only implemented in Google Maps v 3. The github download for infobubble is [here](https://github.com/RelativeMedia/InfoBubble)